# connecting map to json files for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

this is possibly a really simple question, but i can't seem to find the answer or explanation anywhere.

How and where do I connect a map (where the image files come from)
for the images and names I placed in my JSON, for the images need to apear in my browser window. 
im quite new to JSON and Looping and JS.

Here's my code if you need to look into it, to understand how I'm making it.

JSON;

```
{ "main_object": {

    "imagesJ": ["beak", "cat", "egg", "meel", "milk", "passport", "spoon", "thee"],
    "woorden": ["words", "not", "needed", "yet"]
 }
}
```

```js
//JavaScript

var jsonData = "noJson";
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonData = 'empty';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "./js/data.json",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
      jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

      console.log('ok');
      imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
      woorden = jsonData.main_object.woorden;

      for (i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
        imagesJ[i] + '.jpg';

        // => /img/[imagesJ[x]].jpg
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('JSON could not be loaded.');
    }
  });
  console.log(jsonData);


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sleepopdracht</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="images" id="images"></div>
  </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you want to to is add an [image tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for each image in `imagesJ`.  The structure of your loop is good for that, and you can use [jQuery to `append()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) the image tag to `div id="images"`.  The for-loop would look something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
    var path = imagesJ[i] + '.jpg';
    $('#images').append('<img id="image' + i + '" src="' + path + '" />');
}
```

Comment: thank you, you've helped too with understanding how and what and where i need to do this!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you simply need to create an "img" element, set its "src" attribute and append to "images" node;

Here's how you can do this

```
var titles = ["words", "not", "needed", "yet"];
var imagesContainer = document.getElementById('images');

titles.forEach(function(title){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = '/img/' + title + '.jpg';
    imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vbesoc75/

**EDITED**:

For your concrete example:

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     url: "./js/data.json",
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(response) {
       jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
       console.log('ok');
       imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
       woorden = jsonData.main_object.woorden;

       var imagesContainer = document.getElementById('images');
       for (i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
         var img = document.createElement('img')
         img.src = '/img/' + imagesJ[i];
         imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
       }
    },
```

Comment: it does help me quite well on the way, altough does that 

    var titles = ["words", "not", "needed", "yet"]; 

has to be there? because I already have the array in jason, isn't it possible to keep those in the JSON but into JS too?

I did try it like how you've put it, but it's not working..

Comment: I just wanted to show you how you can generate new images and append them to specified node;
For your example you can do it inside of the "for" loop. Let me edit my answer to help you